# ObjectDataSource is sending empty values for update

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, objectdatasource

I have an **ObjectDataSource Control** which is binding to a **DetailsView** and it works perfectly for SELECT. However for Updating its not passing me an object with any assigned (bound) properties.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsExample" runat="server" 
     TypeName="AppClassObjects.GetDataExample" DataObjectTypeName="AppClassStructures.Example" 
    SelectMethod="GetEWxampleData" UpdateMethod="UpdateExampleData" 
    ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="995229" Name="fphi_FieldProjectHeaderItemsID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

Public Function UpdateSPRData(original_Example As AppClassStructures.Example, 
                            Example As AppClassStructures.Example) As Integer

    ''do stuff
End Function
```

I just converted the Update to using an all parameter values and that does work. I really do not want to pass around 20 parameters though, I would really much rather get the ObjectDataSource to pass the event an Object.

Comment: I do not understand why my markup code is not in the question

Comment: you need to post the full code. I also see that you have not posted your "UpdateExampleData" function, but you have "UpdateSPRData" function... these are different

Comment: Need the markup, but I have experienced issues where a binding error causes this: type mismatch, etc. To debug, you could comment out chunks of you markup and see if it works minimally, then add back until it fails.